# Visual Studio 2022 Create Azure TimeTrigger function results in empty solution with no files

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio, azure-functions

When I try to create   a 'Timer Trigger' app from the 'New Solution' template Visual Studio Professional 2022 (Create New Project -> Azure Functions -> Timer Trigger) creates empty solution (0 Projects). This happens when I try to create a project based on any of the Azure function templates. There isn't any error given and I'm not sure what to do. Any thoughts on how I might resolve this problem?

What I've tried so far:

1. Uninstalling then reinstalling Visual Studio and this didn't fix the problem.
2. Removing and adding again Azure Development tools from VS Installer.
3. Installing azure tools a different way: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/1872 (npm i -g azure-functions-core-tools@4 --unsafe-perm true)
4. Running the command line uninstaller as directed by Microsoft Tech Support Chat.

More information: The resulting solution is empty and there is no project or files generated. Here is what the *.sln file looks like:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio Version 17
VisualStudioVersion = 17.1.32210.238
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals) = postSolution
        SolutionGuid = {6DC061D5-7D34-4A91-9A50-47AC1A22F53C}
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

This problem wound up with a Microsoft Support team. We installed and reinstalled multiple times to no effect. In the end I installed Visual Studio on another computer and it ran with no problems whatsoever. As a result I decided to reimage my PC. After reimage Visual Studio worked as expected.

Comment: This is also happening for queue & HTTP triggered functions, I haven't checked more templates than that. I know of others in different geographic locations with the same problem.

Comment: updating to 17.1.0 made no difference

Comment: I wound up reimaging the computer. That fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing and adding again Azure Development tools from VS Installer.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I did as you suggested but it didn't change the result. The azure functions projects are still empty solutions.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is fixed in the latest version of Visual Studio 2022 (17.1.1). In order to get the template working for me again I had to do the following:

1. Update to 17.1.1
2. Delete AzureFunctionsTemplate.vstemplate
3. Run a repair of Visual Studio
4. Reboot

I compared the vstemplate file from before and after the process and it was 100% the same so a repair might work without having to delete the template file.

Answer (score 0):

This problem wound up with a Microsoft Support team. We installed and reinstalled multiple times to no effect. In the end I installed Visual Studio on another computer and it ran with no problems whatsoever. As a result I decided to reimage my PC. After reimage Visual Studio worked as expected.

This isn't really an answer. More for the next person who comes to Stack who is experiencing this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is over a year old and the OP found a work around, but for anyone experiencing this problem, try moving the solution folder closer to your root folder, like in C:\Projects and also try shortening the project name.

After trying every solution I could find online I had actually given up and asked a coworker(who uses a Mac) to just create a new solution from the Azure Functions template and upload it to a Git repo so that I could just clone it and get to work.

Trying to clone that repo gave me a semi useful error message that the project failed to load.

> C:\Users[long file path with client information].csproj : error  : The expression "[MSBuild]::NormalizePath(C:\Users[long file path with client information], obj\Debug\net6.0[long file path with client information].assets.cache)" **cannot be evaluated.**

> Path: C:\Users[long file path with client information]\obj\Debug\net6.0[long file path with client information].assets.cache **exceeds the OS max path limit. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters.**

I tried creating an Azure Functions project again, but this time in a directory closer to the root, and with a shorter file name, and it worked.