# Where does Visual Studio Professional 2022 put the default templates for Azure Functions?

Tags: azure, visual-studio, azure-functions

When I try to create a new Azure Function: (Create New Project -> Azure Functions -> Timer Trigger) I get a blank solution with no projects (Projects(0)).

I've reinstalled Visual Studio and the associated Add-Ons multiple times.

Where can I find the default templates for Visual Studio Professional 2022?

Comment: In my VS 2022 I can create an empty, default Timer Trigger function from the project template. Have you got the Azure dev package installed via Visual Studio installer?

Comment: The Azure dev package is installed. It lets me create a solution/project without error but that solution is empty and there is no project. Here is my original question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71302281/visual-studio-2022-create-azure-timetrigger-function-results-in-empty-solution-w

Answer (score 0):

One of the workaround is to download the .NET desktop development. Navigate to **Tools >> Get Tools and Features >> check .NET Desktop Development >> Install.**

[image]

[image]