# Why Does Visual Studio 2022 Make Empty Folder with Solution Name?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm creating a simple console app in Visual Studio, with a project name: MyProject and solution name: MySolution. I created it in a previously empty repo I cloned from Azure Devops.

Folder Structure:

MySolution

- MyProject
- MySolution    <--- ?????????
- MySolution.sln

Why does that empty folder get created? Can I safely delete it?

I just upgraded to VS 2022, and I don't remember this folder getting created before in VS 2019. I was expecting this folder not to exist. I checked and there are no hidden files it it.

Comment: If there are no files in the folder then it should be safe to delete it. Out of interest, what was in the repo you cloned? Was that folder present there?

Comment: The repo was brand new and it contained a single git ignore file.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71302281/visual-studio-2022-create-azure-timetrigger-function-results-in-empty-solution-w) can help you?